# Add Rows and copy formulas from Row before - Timeout

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large sheet with over 4000 rows and 30 columns.
I am trying to automaticly add new rows to the sheet if there are less than x "empty" rows. Empty rows are defined by just containing formulas but the data column A is empty.

To check if a row is empty or not I check column A, because you have to enter data in column A. After adding new rows the script should copy/paste the last row before over the new rows, so they contain the formulas as well.

**Here is the script (PREVIOUS VERSION):**

```
  function addRowsItems() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('items');  

  var freeRows = 300; // Number of empty Rows after last Entry

  var lRow = sh.getLastRow(), lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);

  var startRow = lRow-freeRows;

  if(startRow < 0) {
    startRow = 1; }

  var values = sh.getRange("A" + startRow + ":A").getValues(); 
  var maxIndex = values.reduce(function(maxIndex, row, index) {
    return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
  }, 0);

  var maxIndex = maxIndex + startRow;

  var space = lRow - maxIndex;
  var addLines = freeRows - space;

  if(space < freeRows) {

     sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, addLines); 
     range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, addLines, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});

    }
  }
```

This is working in a new sheet with less data.
But using it in the main sheet with over 4000 rows of data I get a time out. The script adds the new rows but it times out before it is able to copy/paste.

Why is it taking so much time? Is there an easier way to achieve that?

**So this is the actual version. Cell B1 contains `COUNBLANK` of Range A:A.**

```
function addRowsItems() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('items');  

  var freeRows = 307; // Number of empty Rows after last Entry

  var lRow = sh.getMaxRows(), lCol = sh.getMaxColumns(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  var space = sh.getRange("B1").getValues();
  var addLines = freeRows - space;

  if(space < freeRows) {

     sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, addLines); 
     range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, addLines, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `COUNTBLANK` function returns a count of empty cells in a range. Cells that contain text, numbers, errors, etc. are not counted. Formulas that return empty text are counted.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is faster than the `maxIndex` part. The advantage of the `maxIndex` part, finding the first empty cell after the last cell with data is ignorable in this case because there are not that many blank cells inbetween. So `COUNTBLANK` does the work. I also changed `getLastRow` to `getMaxRows` as it seems to be way faster as well.